# How to obtain a group of post meta and assign each meta to other variables?

Tags: post-meta

I saved a group of data in post meta, now I need to get the meta and use them as other items. My code not working, please help me correct it, thanks!

```
$boxes = Array( 'height', 'width' );

foreach ( $boxes as $data ){
$project = get_post_meta($post->ID, $data, true);
}

$item_a = $project->height;
$item_b = $project->width;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($boxes as $data) {
  $project[$data] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $data, true);
}


$item_a = $project['height'];
$item_b = $project['width'];
```